# Unit test fail by comparing mockk objects

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, android-livedata, mockk

I've implemented a `Repository`class like this:

```
class Repository @Inject constructor(private val dao: Dao) {

val response: LiveData<List<MyObject>> = dao.getAllObjects()
...
}
```

Now I wrote a simple unit test for that peace of code like this:

```
class RepositoryTest {

@MockK
private lateinit var mockLiveData: LiveData<List<MyObject>>

@MockK
private lateinit var mockDao: Dao

@InjectMockKs
private lateinit var repository: Repository

init {
    MockKAnnotations.init(this, relaxed = true)
}

@Test
fun `Verify my objects are loaded from the database`() {
    // arrange
    every { dao.getAllObjects() } returns mockLiveData
    // assert
    verify { dao.getAllObjects() }
    assertEquals(this.mockLiveData, repository.response)
}
```

The `assertEquals` check fails with error:

```
Expected :LiveData(mockLiveData#2)
Actual   :LiveData(child of mockDao#5#7)
```

I do not understand why the objects are not equal and how can I rewrite  this test to verify that the livedata objects are equal?

Answer (score 1):

Cause of your problem is sequence of setting things up.
Looking at your sample the order is :

1. Injecting mock into your test suite
2. Creating repository with injected mocks
3. At the single test level binding dao method with result in form of `mockLiveData`
4. Expecting proper liveData in repository field

As you can notice in step 2 by using annotation you have already binded dao with repository, and by default `dao.getAllObjects` returns some mock(child of mockDao).
That is the reason of failing assert.

Solution for your problem is to stop using annotation `@InjectMockks`  and intialize repository lazy.

```
...
private val repository by lazy {
   Repository(dao)
}

@Test
fun `Verify my objects are loaded from the database`() {
    every { dao.getAllObjects() } returns mockLiveData
    assertEquals(this.mockLiveData, repository.response)
}
```

Cheers